# How to use WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

```
 TransferManager.UploadAsync(@"C:\data2.flac",
                             destinationBlob,
                             null,
                             context,
                             CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

This code perfectly works when I upload to `block blob` storage.

How can I use `WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement` when I upload to `page blob`?

Now I get

`Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException: File size 274.02MB is invalid for PageBlob, must be a multiple of 512 bytes.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, in order to upload a file as page blob the size of the file must be a multiple of 512 bytes. Because your file does not match this criteria, your upload is failing. You would need to specify a file which matches this size restriction.

The reason there's this size restriction is because you mount these page blobs as drives and use them with your Virtual Machines.

Comment: So what do I need to do? Resize my file before upload?

Comment: Why do you need to save this as page blob? Can you please explain?

Comment: Because the VHD must be stored as a page blob

Comment: I think resizing the disk is your only option at this time. I'm curious as to how you end up creating this odd sized vhd.

Comment: However I would double check if the VHD is not corrupted before resizing. Please make sure that it is mountable before going through the upload process.